# What happens when I edit an old question of mine?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to improve my standing in SO, so I'm editing and trying to improve some of my older questions.

This morning I updated a question from last year. What happens to a question when I edit it?

My goal is to edit my older bad questions so that they're accepted by the community. Hopefully, they'll help other people also.

Comment: Point of clarification: It would appear from their profile activity that OP has been editing old questions that they themselves asked, not the questions of other people.

Comment: Don't improve questions too much! In particular, don't improve them to the point where they invalidate existing answers!

Comment: @MrLister Uh, I think I'd challenge the premise that the extent to which an edit invalidates existing answers is a simple function of the extent to which it improves the question. I'm pretty sure I can very easily make edits that invalidate all existing answers while simultaneously making the question much worse on its own merits.

Comment: Do improve existing questions, if it reflects the intent and clarifies. If that invalidates answers that are bad, so be it. If you retrospectively figure out a better answer, post it.

Answer (score 24):

Editing a question (in addition to posting and getting an answer) puts it at the top of the [list of active questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).

If a question is On Hold (closed less than 5 days ago) and it is the first time it's been edited [by anyone except users who voted-to-close or flagged the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078), that edit sends it into the Reopen Queue where reviewers vote on whether to reopen the question.

Also, good edits to your title and the questions tags may make it easier to find.

Comment: Note that because OP has less than 2k reputation, editing questions/answers simply adds them to the suggested edits queue for them to be looked over by people with over 2k rep, but otherwise spot on.

Comment: @Tas OP is actually talking about editing their own questions.

Comment: Also note that [edits from users who voted-to-close, or flagged, the question do not put the question in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078).

Comment: Does that mean that an user can purposedly put his old question into spotlight by bumping it to the SE homepage with an otiose edit (like replacing some word with synonyms)? If so, isn't this a bypassing of the bounty system? (if it haven't been done already, I'm willing to ask a meta question about this.)

Comment: @Neinstein Technically you can bump a post by making edits like that but 1) I imagine a moderator would step in if they were caught doing it and 2) getting a question on the top of the recently active list is *nowhere near as good* as putting a bounty on it. Note that just posting a question counts as new activity so the active list moves just as fast the recent list. The list of bountied questions, on the other hand, usually only has 350 - 450 questions on it.

Comment: @BSMP 1) is perfectly valid. But (from my own experience) for 2) I'd argue that for low-rep users bountying a question is something they'd avoid as it'd have a relatively huge negative impact on their rep. Most of my question got 90% of it's views on the first 1-2 days (while it's on the active list), so making an edit could potentially double that, isn't it? It's not that effective as bountying, right, but still pretty effective. And free.